# kivymd: Unknown class <IconLeftWidgetWithoutTouch>

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I´m currently building up a kivymd navigation drawer with a MDList. 
For my davigation drawer I want list items to have icons and text. Kivymd´s documentation therefore states two possible solutions: 
[kivymd list documentation](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/list/)

1. `IconLeftWidget`: icon and widget are touchable
2. `IconLeftWidgetWithoutTouch`: only widget at whole touchable

`Kivymd.uix.list` does provide the `IconLeftWidget` but obviously not `IconLeftWidgetWithoutTouch` 
as I run into the error:
`Unknown class <IconLeftWidgetWithoutTouch>`

Does anyone have more information on the availability of this statet feature `IconLeftWidgetWithoutTouch` ? 
Or did anyone else encounter said error when trying to use this feature?

[Edit]
I´m using the most recent packages: 
Kivy 2.0.0 
kivymd 0.104.2

Comment: Your question mixes the names `IconLeftWidgetWithoutTouch` and `IconLeftWithoutTouchWidget`.  The first of those is the one that actually exists.

Comment: @jasonharper Oh didn´t see that mistake while writing the question. I updated the question as the error is and was originally for `IconLeftWidgetWithoutTouch`. <br> `IconLeftWithoutTouchWidget` was just me trying if maybe kivymd´s developer did a misspelling but they did not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you are running an old version of kivymd, which does not include the `IconLeftWidgetWithoutTouch` class (added in v1.0.0). The current "latest" version on PyPi is `0.104.2`, but the "latest" version on the docs is `1.0.0.dev0`.

You can install an up-to-date version from source as [shown here](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started/):

> If you want to install development version from master branch, you
> should specify link to zip archive:
>
> ```
> pip install https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip
> ```
>
> *Tip*: Replace master.zip with <commit hash>.zip (eg 51b8ef0.zip) to download KivyMD from specific commit.

Comment: Thank you very much. 
It was in fact a version issue.